# Limit of sequence $\{\frac{0}{1/n}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Maybe a silly question. What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{0}{1/n}$? I think it's $0$, as by enumeration the sequence $\{\frac{0}{1/n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{0,0,0,...\}$, which is a constant sequence of $0$. But on the other hand, in the limit we have $\frac{0}{0}$, is this going to cause a problem? Thanks!

Comment: I think it’s $0$

Comment: Thank you very much, does it have something to do with the order of operation so that we must compute each term in the sequence first and then take limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{0}{(1/n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty } 0=0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you tried to evaluate the limit directly, using the rule $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x)},$$ you’d get the indeterminate form $\frac00$. This does not necessarily imply that the limit doesn’t exist or anything like that, just that we can’t evaluate it in this manner. However, by noticing that $\frac{0}{\frac1n}=0$ for any $n\neq0$, we immediately notice that we’re taking the limit of a constant function, which is the constant value itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed clarification!